# Dispatching Thunk to the store with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

In my main store.ts I have this:

```html
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

store.dispatch(fetchUser());
```

So on the first render it dispatches and action to fetchUser to see if he/she can see the content.

This is the thunk:

```html
export const fetchUser = (): ThunkAction<
  void,
  TRootState,
  null,
  Action
> => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.get(GET_USER_INFORMATION);

  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_USER,
    payload: response.data
  });
};
```

But Typescript throws an error:

```html
src/store/index.ts
(14,16): Argument of type 'ThunkAction<void, { userReducer: any; }, null, Action<any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type 'ThunkAction<void, { userReducer: any; }, null, Action<any>>'.
```

store/index.ts line 14:

```
store.dispatch(fetchUser())
```

Honestly, I'm lost. How can I fix that? I don't want to type 'any' in the thunk.

Comment: You should also post `src/store/index.ts`.so that people can view Line 14 and can answer your question..

Comment: Sorry, is just calling store.dispatch(fetchUser())

Comment: You can try two things: 1. `store.dispatch<any>(fetchUser())`; 2. try typing dispatch itself to `ThunkDispatch<>`. You will have to get the type parameters right though, but as far as I remember, it's similar to how you type `ThunkAction`.

Comment: is there a solution for this question?

Answer (score 0):

store.dispatch only accepts an action, not function. but the thunk overrides it. you need to specify the thunk type.

try this

`composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk as ThunkMiddleware<RootState, RootAction>))`

also, check this [official docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/master/test/typescript.ts)